# ERROR: definition of module 'airline_ticket' is not available;

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I am a beginner of C ++ ed. I haven't been able to get the modules to work for a couple of days. As a compiler I use gcc. To compile I type: `gcc -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts -o AirlineTicket AirlineTicket.cppm AirlineTicket.cpp main.cpp` and I get these errors:

```
definition of module 'airline_ticket' is not available; use -fmodule-file= to specify path to precompiled module interface
module airline_ticket;

AirlineTicket.cpp:3:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AirlineTicket'
AirlineTicket::AirlineTicket()
```

Below I have attached the files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello wordl" << endl;
}
```

AirlineTicket.cppm

```
export module airline_ticket;
#include <string>

export class AirlineTicket
{
public:
    AirlineTicket(); ~AirlineTicket();
    double calculatePriceInDollars();
    std::string getPassengerName();
    void setPassengerName(std::string name);
    int getNumberOfMiles();
    void setNumberOfMiles(int miles);
    bool hasEliteSuperRewardsStatus();
    void setHasEliteSuperRewardsStatus(bool status); private:
    std::string m_passengerName;
    int m_numberOfMiles;
    bool m_hasEliteSuperRewardsStatus;
};
```

AirlineTicket.cpp

```
module airline_ticket;

AirlineTicket::AirlineTicket()
{
// Initialize data members.
    m_passengerName = "Unknown Passenger"; m_numberOfMiles = 0; m_hasEliteSuperRewardsStatus = false;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use separate compilation to create the module first. Then you can use the module when building your `main.cpp` program. You must also include the class definition in your `AirlineTicket.cpp` file, or the compiler won't know what the `AirlineTicket` symbol is.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): The `-std=c++2a -fmodules-ts` options say that you are working with experimental and probably  incomplete implementations. To learn using the real stuff you should upgrade your compiler. Note that even in GCC11 Modules aren't yet 100% complete.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I do as you said it gives me this error:  error: `translation unit contains multiple module declarations.   module airline_ticket;
`

Comment: Have you read a tutorial on how to create modules with separate interface and implementation using GCC, like [this one](https://blog.feabhas.com/2021/08/c20-modules-with-gcc11/#Separate_Interface_and_Implementation_files)?